# Azure stream analytics how to flatten json array

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have a task where i need to flatten some json arrays
say my sample json is and i want to flatten the two arrays temperature_Readings and airpollution readings i.e my result must have 5 rows and the columns for air_pollution(array value) should be empty

How do I do this?

Sample JSON

```
    {
        "sensor_readings": {
            "readings":{
            "temperature_readings": [
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "12",
                    "second": "00",
                    "temperature": "22.12C"
                },
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "13",
                    "second": "00",
                    "temperature": "22.2C"
                },
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "14",
                    "second": "00",
                    "temperature": "12.12C"
                },
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "15",
                    "second": "00",
                    "temperature": "22.12C"
                },
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "16",
                    "second": "00",
                    "temperature": "22.12C"
                }
            ]
        
    ,
        "air_pollution_readings": 
            [
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "12",
                    "second": "00",
                    "element":"o3",
                    "particulate": "2.2"
                },
                {
                    "date": "02-02-2020",
                    "hour": "13",
                    "second": "00",
                    "element":"o3",
                    "particulate": "2.1"
                }
            ]}
        }
        ,
        "siteid": "a1234566",
        "deviceid": "2343434"
    }
```

Thanks
Regards
Priya

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of how you can 'unpack' your array of readings.

```
with sensorReadings as (Select sensor_readings.readings.temperature_readings from input),
inputValues as (Select message.ArrayValue as Data from sensorReadings CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(sensorReadings.temperature_readings) as message)


SELECT *
INTO output
FROM inputValues
```

Comment: Thanks for that I am able to unpack the arrays using GetArrayElements but my real problem was to flatten both arrays and join them such that I have 5 values for the temperature and 2 for the air pollution arrays

Comment: Ok, how do you map 5 rows of temperature to 2 items from air pol. ? Based on which criteria, or something like that?